# Trying to make a TableviewCell call a cell number

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

In my app I have a page which saves a contact's name, amount they owe, and cell number. I have two sections. One section is the list of people you owe, and the other section is the list of people that owe you. When the user taps on someone, I want to be able to automatically call the user's cell number. This is what I have so far.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OwedMoney"];
        NSMutableArray *storedCellNumbers = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
        NSString *cellNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [storedCellNumbers valueForKey:@"youOweCellNum"]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellNumber]];

    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *myFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]     initWithEntityName:@"TheyOweMoney"];
        NSMutableArray *storedCellNums = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:myFetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
        NSString *ThecellNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [storedCellNums valueForKey:@"theyOweCellNum"]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ThecellNumber]];

    }
}
```

But so far when a user taps on the cell nothing happens. I'm not sure what's going on. I made sure the cell number was saved here:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context =  [self managedObjectContext];
OwedMoney *owedMoney = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OwedMoney" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[owedMoney setValue:self.cellNum.text forKey:@"youOweCellNum"];
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: 100 people surveyed, number one answer still on the board, show me: "Didn't Set Delegate"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you've set the table's delegate.

If you've created the table view in interface builder, you can right click on it and click drag from "delegate" to the file you want to be the delegate for the tableview.

Otherwise, it's as simple as this:

```
myTableView.delegate = someDelegateObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table view's delegate is setup.

`@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Then set the table views delegate

```
table.delegate = self;
```

You can double check by setting an `NSLog` or breakpoint in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and see if it is called or not.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to do that in the .h Im archiving the project right now and will test on a mobile device